# core plot with static axis

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

How to make both axis static, but plots movable? I mean only move plots (what is inside axis), but not axis. My client hate that axis and their labels move together. 
Is it possible to make such things, so my client will be happy?

Comment: Do you mean lock the axes in position, but allow the ticks, gridlines, and labels to move with the plots?

Comment: @EricSkroch Yes, I would like that

Comment: I am out of that project, but I think it was 1.0 or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `axisConstraints` on each axis.

```
x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```